# App Inventor bad resolution

Tags: android

I was creating an app with [MIT AppInventor](http://appinventor.mit.edu/) and there is a problem. When i run the app the screen's app has bad resolution so the text and the buttons gets blury.

[Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s2cumrd5vrm7ef7/Screenshot_2014-06-15-16-49-36.png)

I'm using Samsung Galaxy Tab 3

Answer (score 1):

To avoid blurry graphics set the size of all your buttons, sprites and components using values from the **power of two table** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_two)

For example a good button will bet set to Height= 128 x 64 or 128 x 32 . Also consider these values when you make your graphics (png, jpg, gif etc).
If you want to change the size of a button for example make sure values are divisible by 2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if tablets aren't compatible with app inventor yet (I am using a tablet and it has glitches) try packaging your app or if you already have delete the app then re-install it.
For more info, go to http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/share.html